# boundary conditions - inhomogenius liniar pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have this boundary conditions question:

$2\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-14\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=3(x+y)$

Where the boundary conditions are:

$u(x,-6x)=Cos((2x)^2) \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

I don't understand the boundary conditions.
Also, what would a proper substitution of variables be?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boundary value gives you value of $u(x,y)$ on the line $y=-6x$ or curve $(t,-6t)$. you can try to introduce two different variables to make the equation integrable. like
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{}
\xi = a_1 x+a_2y \\
\eta = b_1x+b_2y
\end{array}
\right. \tag{1} \label{1}
$$
you can easily guess $\xi$ as $x+y$, because of RHS (we want the PDE to be integrable ODE after substitution). and for second one insert $\eqref{1}$ in PDE
$$
(2-14) \frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} + \underbrace{(2b_1-14b_2)}_{\text{Want to be 0}} \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta} = 3 \xi
$$
so we can choose $$
b_1 = 7 , b_2 = 1 \rightarrow \eta=7x+y
$$
therefore the PDE becomes:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} = -\frac{1}{4}\xi \Rightarrow u=-\frac{1}{8}\xi^2 + g(\eta) 
$$
Finally we get
$$
u(x,y) = -\frac{1}{8} (x+y)^2 + g(7x+y). \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
now you can use boundary condition
$$
u(x,-6x) = -\frac{1}{8} (5x)^2 + g(x) = \cos(4x^2)
$$
hence :
$$
g(z) = \cos(4z^2)+\frac{25}{8} x^2 \\
\Rightarrow g(7x+y) = \cos(4(7x+y)^2)+\frac{25}{8} (7x+y)^2.
$$
put this back into $\eqref{2}$ and you're done.

Comment: I'm not inertly sure as to how cos(2x^2) becomes cos(4x^2) and whats the point of using z?

Comment: in your question the boundary is $\cos((2x)^2) = \cos(4x^2)$ but if it's a typo you can consider $\cos(2x^2)$. and for $z$ i just wanted to emphasize that we have function $g(.)$ for for its argument clearly and don't need any substitution to find $g(.)$. and i put $z=7x+y$ to find the final answer.

Comment: Thank you. That cleared it up. Its no typo it's just me that's a bit slow.

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.